# Extraterritorial Scope of Brazil's LGPD

Tags: gdpr

How can a national legislation, like the recent Brazil's LGPD apply to companies which are not established in Brazil, but may offer services to Brazilian citizens via the Internet?

Imagine a website (hosted outside Brazil) never tracks the location of its registered users (which can easily be altered anyway using a VPN). How can Brazil even enforce the application of its national laws in such cases? What can it do if the company in question simply refuses to comply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Like this

Let's assume that the perpetrator is a California based company.

1. The Brazilian government initiates a prosecution in Brazil.
2. It follows its proper course and the company is convicted and the judge orders a fine of, say 5 million Real.
3. The Brazilian government takes this judgment to a Californian court who determines that the case was conducted correctly under Brazilian law. This would be a judicial review and not a retrial on the issues. Further, they would check that the matter was not in conflict with ant treaty between the US & Brazil about such matters.
4. If the Californian court is satisfied that this was done correctly, it issues a judgment for the same amount in USD.
5. The Brazillian government then collects against that debt using all the normal methods in California. Refusal by the company to pay will now be contempt of court in California.

Virtually every country in the world reciprocally enforces judgements for other nations.

By the way, there is no extraterritoriality in the offence: the offence was committed in Brazil and prosecuted in Brazil, the enforcement is under US law in California.