# At first UK, then EU, then GERMANY, then GDRP, now LGPD ... How far we will be enforced to comply with other countries extraterritorial laws?

Tags: privacy, gdpr, data-protection

*(these are somehow related questions: [1](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65706/what-imprint-do-i-have-to-use-to-comply-with-various-international-laws), [2](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/108182/is-it-required-to-list-each-cookie-by-name-to-comply-with-eu-uk-cookie-laws), [3](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/48744/extraterritorial-scope-of-brazils-lgpd); but not duplicate ). Also, if you downvote, please comment the reason of downvoting, and don't see the rant where it is not.*

---

Original question:

We (website owners) are endlessly required to comply with any new law whatever is invented by any country. Once in every new period, each country takes a new law which enforce world users to comply with their laws.
(UK asks this, GDRP asks that, Germany asks to reveal website holder information, now LGPD asks something [i dont know]).

And there are 250+ countries:

[image]

And we have to comply all of each country's law (whenever why invent something).
Strange, crazy and **unlegit** (why I should comply with i.e. *Burgundia's* law?
Website (generally - internet) is not a material property like factory, retail store or mine, as they have to have chosen physical location & audience), but internet/website is absolutely opposite thing by concept (a place without a  physical presense), and world-wide-web (call it DNS systems, IANA or ICANN) distributes it to all over the world (so, we don't intentionally register websites in Burgundia, thus we are not responsible if our website is accessed from Burgundia. If they don't like our website's privacy & terms, then don't use that website), and people enters our websites all over the world and we have no idea from where users enter. So, why or how we are forced to created algorithms to detect from which country user comes, then learn all those countries legislation and for each country have appropriate terms? Per an average mortal website-owner, this seems just insane and dream.

Is not there any treaty or organisation that gives us (website owners) some freedom & protects us from other countries' illegit requirements?

---

*btw. I used "Burgundia" as a phseudo country name not to offence anyone.*

Comment: It should be pointed out that those who make laws are often far from competent in terms of the technology they're legislating for.

Comment: There are so many misconceptions and misrepresentations of legal and political reality and theory here that it's not possible to explain them all without simply repeating many existing answers.

Comment: Can anyone tell (explain) why so many donwvotes?

Comment: Re the question on downvotes, there may be a legitimate question in there, but the tone is very much that of a rant.

Comment: @o.m. if it were rant the topic has been deleted by mod, however, you gone a bit more far, that you even reject emotions in people (which is natural toward the stupid and insane things) and try to the see rant where there is no rant.

Comment: so, the reason of downvote is that you feel there a tone of rant. ok. thanks for feedback.got me amused :)

Comment: @T.Todua, currently there are three out of five necessary close votes. And six downvotes to one upvote.

Comment: "Burgundia" is the Latin spelling of Burgundy/Bourgogne, a historical Region of France till 2015, and an area. The (modern) area is known for its wine (Burgundy) and mustard (Dijon). The name *also* is applied to the Burgundian Kingdom (conquered by the Franks in 532) which was re-created as a part of the Frankian Empire. In fact, there were at one point **three** Burgundias in existence: Upper B. in the Swiss, Lower B. in Provence (united in 937 and integrated into the HRE in 1032), Duchy of B. near Saône (integrated into France in 1004). Add the County of B. (12th century) as recreation...

Comment: if you need a pseudocountry, use [Ruritania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruritania) or [Something-stan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-stan).

Comment: @Trish haha, thanks :) changing now.

Answer (score 2):

### You don’t need to comply with these laws

Just stop operating in their country.

If you choose to operate in a country, by operating a mine, a retail store, a factory or, say, a web site, then that country has a right, recognised by all other countries, to require you to abide by their laws while doing so. Once you start interacting with users through your website (cookies, login, eCommerce) you are “operating” where your users are and are subject to the applicable law. If you were to require your users to declare that they were citizens of and presently in, say, Azerbaijan, then only Azerbaijani law would apply.

There is also a basic rule of law that *you* are responsible for informing yourself of the law relevant to your activities and to comply with it. [Ignorantia juris non excusat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignorantia_juris_non_excusat).

Comment: @T.Todua yes there are - they are called law firms that specialise in trans-national IP.

Comment: neither i meant law-firms. i surely know there exist law firms or atornees out there. (you should have noticed my emphasize on `,. if there is any treaty or orgnaization that protects us...`, so neither your another answer actually answered the question i asked, instead you answered to the different issue, which I (OP) have not asked. (in addition to the very first senescence of your answer, which could have answered a theoretical question if someone asked "do i need to comply...").  anyway, frankly, thanks for taking time, i really appreciate your attempt to answer the question.

Comment: I think the main problem here is that your English is perhaps not quite as good as you think. Your comment above uses 'senescence' quite wrongly - unless your were intending an insult - although the word is spelt quite correctly. Your grammar is subtly off. Your first *sentence* above is not a correct sentence (but the meaning is clear). It does come off like a rant. I good question might be 'How can I protect myself from all these variable and changing international laws?', but you have rant-like essay instead.